# equals sign in Python's argument

Tags: python, syntax, python-2.7, arguments

I'd like to put be able launch python's scripts from the shell command line in a following manner:

```
python script_name -temp=value1 -press=value2
```

I wrote sth like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("temp", help="specify the temperature [K]", type=float)
parser.add_argument("press", help="specify the pressure [Pa]", type=float)

args = parser.parse_args()
temp = args.temp
press = args.press
print temp
print press
```

And the imput can be:

```
python script_name value1 value2
```

How to be able to enter the values in manner -arg=value ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `parser.add_argument("--temp", ...)`

There are great examples in the argparser manual:

http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html

**Edit:**

For arguments starting with `-` only the pattern `-argument VALUE` works.
This works also for arguments starting with `--`, but here you can also use the pattern `--argument=VALUE`.

Comment: # isn't working for me
import argparse
vmFullParser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
vmFullParser.add_argument('--domain.vmfull')
value = "-domain.vmfull=\"VM-1,VM-2\""
args, _ = vmFullParser.parse_known_args(value)
print(args)
# thoughts?

Comment: The edit isn't true anymore in the newest python version from what I can tell, i.e. `-argument=VALUE` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

When configured to accept an argument of the form "-argument VALUE" argparse will automatically also accept that parameter in the form "-argument=VALUE"